# Subtracting from an Integer within a do-while loop

Tags: java

I'm generally new to programming and just started programming in Java a few days ago so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is even possible with the way my program is coded.

I'm basically writing a program that asks for a "Strength" value between 0 and 9. It asks you to choose a weapon ((1) Knife is the only one available). It takes that information and generates a random damage ratio between 1-3 plus what ever number your strength is and is **supposed** to keep subtracting that value from 20 until it hit 0 then quits.

The problem is that I'm stuck in a loop. It subtracts the value from 20, but starts over and keeps subtracting from 20 again rather than storing the subtracted number.

Does anyone have any advice on how something like this would be accomplished? Any help is very much appreciated. This is my code so far....

```
package untitledgame;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class UntitledGame {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        int pStrength, wKnife, damage, enemyDamage;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  //used for next to int inputs

        System.out.println("Choose Your Strength (0-9)");
        pStrength = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your Strength Is "+pStrength);

        System.out.println("Choose Your Weapon; (1)Knife");
        wKnife = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Press ENTER to battle...");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  //waits for users to continue
        scanner.nextLine();



        if (wKnife == 1){


        do {

            int enemyHP = 20;

            Random rn = new Random();  //Random generator
            wKnife = rn.nextInt(3) + 1;  //Randomly generates knife damage


            damage = wKnife + pStrength;  //Damage logic
            System.out.println("Attack with knife has done: " );  //Knife damage     
            System.out.print(+damage);
            System.out.print(" damage." );

            System.out.println("");

            enemyDamage = enemyHP - damage;  // Remaing HP 

            System.out.println("Enemy has ");
            System.out.print(+enemyDamage);
            System.out.print(" HP left.");

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Press Enter to Attack...");         
            scanner.nextLine();  

        } 
            while (enemyDamage > 0);

            System.out.println("Enemy has been defeated.");


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare this `int enemyHP = 20;` outside the `do-while` loop. Right now, you're resetting `enemyHP` to 20 every single time you iterate through the loop.

Also, you should not recreate your `Random` within the `do-while` loop. Do that before entering the `do` block.

There are other issues with the logic that Jonah Haney deals with in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int enemyHP = 20` before the beginning of the loop. Then your loop is missing the following line:

```
enemyHP = enemyHP - damage;
```

Also, it seems that you want the loop to keep running until the enemy has been defeated. If that is the case, then your condition should check to see if `enemyHP` has been drained all the way, like this:

```
}
    while (enemyHP > 0);    //instead of while (enemyDamage > 0);
```

**EDIT**

This is what your code SHOULD look like. I am not saying you should copy it straight into your project. I am saying that you should take a look at the differences and it will help you see the logic problems in your own code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int pStrength, wKnife, damage, enemyDamage;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  //used for next to int inputs

    System.out.println("Choose Your Strength (0-9)");
    pStrength = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your Strength Is " + pStrength);

    System.out.println("Choose Your Weapon; (1)Knife");
    wKnife = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Press ENTER to battle...");
    in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();

    Random rn = new Random();  //Random generator
    int enemyHP = 20;

    if (wKnife == 1){

        do {
            System.out.println("Press Enter to Attack...");         
            in.nextLine();  

            wKnife = rn.nextInt(3) + 1;   //Randomly generates knife damage
            damage = wKnife + pStrength;  //Damage logic

            System.out.println("Attack with knife has done: " + damage + " damage.");  //Knife damage

            enemyHP -= damage;            // Calculate Remaining HP 
            System.out.println("Enemy has " + enemyHP + " HP left.");

        } while (enemyHP > 0);

        System.out.println("Enemy has been defeated.");
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant! Thank you for the information! I think what took me 4 hours you whipped up in 5 minutes lol

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to initialize your enemyHP variable OUTSIDE of the do-while loop, or it will reset enemyHP back to 20 every time it loops.